# Force boost to use POSIX shared memory instead of System V?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, posix, shared-memory

Boost by default is using System V shared memory and creating file for communication. I want it to use POSIX shared memory.

Is their a way to force boost to use POSIX shared memory instead of trying to create a file?

Do I have to change something in source code (Boost.Interprocess)?

I am using 1.46.1 version of boost in my project on OS X (10.6, 10.7 and 10.8). But I can use 1.52.0 too. Before to migrate I want to know if it's even possible to do.

Comment: Which boost library would this be?

Comment: I updated my question. I am using 1.46.1.

Comment: I meant which part of boost?  My best guess is Boost.Interprocess

Comment: oh Yes. Boost.Interprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, Boost Interprocess will use POSIX when available.  Digging further into it, it appears that on Max OSX it does not because the implementation has some non-conforming behavior  (according to the header) .  Below is the code from `boost/interprocess/detail/workaround.hpp`.

```
//Check for XSI shared memory objects. They are available in nearly all UNIX platforms
   #if !defined(__QNXNTO__)
      #define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_XSI_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS
   #endif

   #if defined(_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS) && ((_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS - 0) > 0)
      #define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS
   #else
      //VMS and MACOS don't define it but they have shm_open/close interface
      #if defined(__vms)
         #if __CRTL_VER >= 70200000
            #define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS
         #endif
         //Mac OS has some non-conformant features like names limited to SHM_NAME_MAX
      #elif defined (__APPLE__)
         //#define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS
         //#define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS_NO_GROW
      #endif
   #endif
```

Comment: I tried writing some sample code using posix shared memory objects and they worked nicely. It's just with boost things were easier.

Comment: @MacGeek: I'm sure it works closely, and I'd be curious why, but the current (Boost 1.52) headers won't enable it by default.  You might be able to define `BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS` but I have no idea how well that will work.

Comment: I tried that. Writing process can create SM object and initialize it too, reading process on other hand can create SM object but fails during ftruncate(m_handle, length);

Comment: We have to uncomment BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS and BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS_NO_GROW lines and just make sure reader process is trying to truncate it.